# Mathf.SmoothDamp not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code for recoil concerning rotation on the x-axis.
For some reason my gun will go up but SmoothDamp function does not move my gun/recoilAngle back down for some reason...

```
float recoilRotationSmoothDamp;

public void Update(){

        recoilAngle = Mathf.SmoothDamp (recoilAngle, 0, ref recoilRotationSmoothDamp, 0.25f);
        transform.localEulerAngles = transform.localEulerAngles + Vector3.left * recoilAngle;

    }

public void Shoot(){
    recoilAngle += 2;
    recoilAngle = Mathf.Clamp(recoilAngle, 0, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use a tween engine , like http://dotween.demigiant.com/.

If you install Dotween then you can simply use:

```
public void Shoot(){
    transform.DOShakePosition(float duration, float/Vector3 strength, int vibrato, float randomness, bool snapping, bool fadeOut)
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, but are you sure there isn't a way to make the SmoothDamp function work as it would work perfectly with what i am trying to achieve.